# Implementar la interfaz del iterador

Tags: java

Tengo una funcion `panel1` que devuelve un iterator que funciona con el siguiente programa:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Iterator<Integer> it = panel1(1,5);
     for(;it.hasNext();)
        System.out.println(it.next()); // affiche 1 2 3 4 5
}
```

Para simplificarlo, quiero facilitar el intervalo al admitir la sintaxis de foreach de Java como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo.

```
for(int i:panel2(1,5))
    System.out.println(i); // devuelve 1 2 3 4 5
```

¿Qué interfaz debo implementar para iterar de esta otra manera? Es por decir con una función `panel2` que funcionaria de este manera.

Aqui esta la clase Panel con la función panel1:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Panel{

    public static Iterator<Integer> panel1(final int begin,final int end){
        Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<Integer>(){

            private int nextValue = begin;
            private final int max = end;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nextValue <= max;
            }

            public Integer next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                return Integer.valueOf(nextValue++);
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        return it;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Iterator<Integer> it = panel1(1,5);
         for(;it.hasNext();)
            System.out.println(it.next()); // affiche 1 2 3 4 5
    }
}
```

## Intentos

### Mio intento

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Panel<T> implements Iterable<T>{

    private List<T> list;

    public Panel(T [] in) {

        list = Arrays.asList(in);
        Collections.reverse(list);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> panel2(int begin, int end) {

        Integer [] ints = {1, 2, 3}; // change to things between begin and end
        Panel<Integer> list = new Panel<>(ints);
        return list.iterator();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i:panel2(1,5))
            System.out.println(i); // debe devolver 1 2 3 4 5

    }
}
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien\TD7_iterators>javac Panel.java
Panel.java:7: error: Panel is not abstract and does not override abstract method iterator() in Iterable
public class Panel<T> implements Iterable<T>{
       ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Panel
Panel.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
Panel.java:22: error: incompatible types: Iterator<Integer> cannot be converted to Iterator<T>
        return list.iterator();
                            ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Panel
Panel.java:28: error: non-static method panel2(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context
        for(int i:panel2(1,5))
                  ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Panel
Panel.java:28: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
        for(int i:panel2(1,5))
                        ^
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    Iterator<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Panel
5 errors
```

### Intento con la respuesta de Julio López

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Panel implements Iterable<Integer>{

   int begin;
   int end;

   // alguna lógica acá para llenar los valores de begin y de end, como constructor y/o setter y getter.
    public Panel(int begin, int end){
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {

        return panel1(begin,end);
    }

    private static Iterator<Integer> panel1(final int begin,final int end){
        Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<Integer>(){

            private int nextValue = begin;
            private final int max = end;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nextValue <= max;
            }

            public Integer next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                return Integer.valueOf(nextValue++);
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        return it;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Panel panel = new Panel(1,5);
        for(int i:panel)
          System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien\TD7_iterators>java Panel.java
error: class found on application class path: Panel
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Que exactamente  es lo que esperas que haga?

Comment: @Einer Quiero cambiar `for(;it.hasNext();) System.out.println(it.next());` en `for(int i:panel2(1,5)) System.out.println(i);` Me parece que necesito implementar la interfaz del iterador, no?

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.Iterable.

[Del javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html):

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "for-each loop" statement. See For-each Loop